# @ElementCollection does not store values inside my table (JPA)

Tags: java, jpa

I have a `Set` of `Long` values inside my entity class. I want this Set to store values for particular instances of this class. Here's my code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "accounts")
public class DefaultAccount implements Account {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "email", nullable = false, unique = true)
private String email;

@Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
private String password;

@ElementCollection
private Set<Long> managerAccounts = new HashSet<Long>();

public DefaultAccount(String email, String password) {
        Assert.hasText(email);
        Assert.hasText(password);
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

public DefaultAccount(String email, String password, Set<Long> accounts)  {
        this(email, password);
        Assert.notEmpty(accounts);
        this.managerAccounts.addAll(accounts);
    }

// Getters

}
```

**Persist code:**

```
private EntityManager entityManager;

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "crm-db")
public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}

public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return entityManager;
}

public void createAccount(Account account) {
entityManager.persist(account);
}
```

When using the second constructor to persist a `DefaultAccount` object, JPA does not pass values from `managerAccounts` `Set` to the database. What is the issue for this?

Comment: this.managerAccounts=accounts will not do that?

Comment: it would be better if you post the code of db persistent. !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I tried

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "defaultaccounts")
public class DefaultAccount {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    private Long      id;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String    email;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String    password;

    @ElementCollection
    private Set<Long> managerAccounts = new HashSet<Long>();

    public DefaultAccount(String email, String password) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public DefaultAccount(String email, String password, Set<Long> accounts) {
        this(email, password);
        this.managerAccounts.addAll(accounts);
    }
```

My test code

```
        EntityManager em = // get entity manager from entity manager factory
        em.getTransaction().begin();

        HashSet accounts  = new HashSet();
        accounts.add(new Long(10000));
        accounts.add(new Long(10001));
        accounts.add(new Long(10002));

       DefaultAccount account  =  new DefaultAccount("test@test.com", "test", accounts);
       em.persist(account);

        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
```

Here is the SQL sent to the database ( as **expected** 4 total inserts)

```
insert 
        into
            defaultaccounts
            (email, password) 
        values
            (?, ?)

insert 
        into
            default_account_manager_acc
            (default_account, manager_accounts) 
        values
            (?, ?)

insert 
        into
            default_account_manager_acc
            (default_account, manager_accounts) 
        values
            (?, ?)

insert 
        into
            default_account_manager_acc
            (default_account, manager_accounts) 
        values
            (?, ?)
```

Values persisted in database

```
mysql> select * from defaultaccounts;
+----+---------------+----------+
| id | email         | password |
+----+---------------+----------+
|  1 | test@test.com | test     |
+----+---------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from default_account_manager_acc;
+-----------------+------------------+
| default_account | manager_accounts |
+-----------------+------------------+
|               1 |            10001 |
|               1 |            10000 |
|               1 |            10002 |
+-----------------+------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set accounts to the instance's managerAccounts:

```
public DefaultAccount(String email, String password, Set<Long> accounts)  {
        this(email, password);
        Assert.notEmpty(accounts);
        this.managerAccounts=accounts;
    }
```

should suffice.

Comment: The .addAll() method gives more functionality.

Comment: can you post how you are saving?

Comment: try doing entityManager.flush()